Длина закрытого ключа python requests openssl
Пытаюсь на python requests получать данные из тестовому стенду сервиса. Сервис прислал тестовые сертификаты для подключения в формате pfx с ГОСТ шифрованием. Как я понял, requests не умеет в pfx, поэтому, накатив OpenSSL с поддержкой ГОСТ, достал с его помощью сертификат и ключ в форматах .pem. Ключ проверил в OpenSSL - длина 2048 бит. При попытке отправки POST запроса к сервису получаю ошибку:

Max retries exceeded with url: /uat-ucbcore/report (Caused by
SSLError(SSLError(399, '[SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small
(_ssl.c:3862)')))

По информации из интернета, причиной этой ошибки является тот факт, что версии python от 3.10 (у меня как раз она) не поддерживают длину RSA ключей до 2048 бит, но OpenSSL пишет что всё ок. Техподдержка разводит руками.  Помогите, пожалуйста.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL сообщает нам, что размер ключа эллиптической криптографии слишком мал. Разве у вас эллиптическая криптография? Скорее всего, сервер, с которым вы соединяетесь, использует слабую криптографию. Выполните команду echo -ne '\x04' | openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> и посмотрите размер ключа в выдаче команды. Должно быть что-то вроде PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256. Добавьте сведения о сертификатах сервера в вопрос.

А что Вы сделали чтоб requests стал понимать  ГОСТ?
